# How to define a local function in Constructor.prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi Guys I am facing difficulty in one of scenario where in I m not able to define local function in my Manager.prototype.  Please find below detail..

I have a Constructor Function Employee.

```
function Employee(id){
   this.id = id;
}
Employee.prototype.getID = function(){
    return this.id;
}
var mark = new Employee(123);
```

Again I have a Manager Constructor

```
function Manager(managerOf){
   this.managerOf = managerOf;
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
Manager.prototype.getManagerOf = function(){
    return this.managerOf;
}
var john = new Manager(mark);
```

Now I want to define a function calcSalary() which is only accessible from getManagerOf() method & **not from outside**. [john.calcSalary() should not work]

Comment: Just declare it within the scope of `getManagerOf`. It won't be accessible from outside the function.

Comment: No I wanted it be more generic, so that tomorrow if I add one more prototype function it can be accessible from that one as well, any thoughts?

Comment: There are patterns used to achieve "private" methods in JS. Typically using closures. And the example provided in the answer of @Daniel A. White is a good one.

Comment: If you want your managers to inherit from employee, then you need an `Employee.call(this, id)` call in the `Manager` constructor - currently `john.getID()` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Bergi you are absolutely right, I can do that , but right now my concern is how can we add a generic local function to a prototype which can be accessed by all protoypal functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hide it with a self executing function.

```
var Manager = (function() {
   function calcSalary() {}
   function Manager(managerOf){
      this.managerOf = managerOf;
   }
   Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
   Manager.prototype.getManagerOf = function(){
      // call calcSalary
      return this.managerOf;
   }
   return Manager;
}());

var john = new Manager(mark);
```

Comment: This doesn't seems right, I won't be able to use new keywork on my constructor anymore. Also If I wish to inherit my Manager/Manager.prototype object, then how would I do that?

Comment: @RanjeetGautam i forgot to export it.

Comment: @RanjeetGautam the same way you did for Employee to Manager.

Comment: @DanielA.White, What if `calcSalary()` needs access to the `this` (stateful)?

Comment: @haim770 just pass a reference like `calcSalary(this)`.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel A. White ! This works, I am able to acheive what I wanted. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @DanielA.White, Effectively making it a static / non-instance method, as opposed to a real "private" method that is stateful.

Comment: there's no `private` in javascript @haim770

Comment: @DanielA.White, Obviously, Yet, I was under the impression that's what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @DanielA.White FYI: This JS construct you re advising is called “immediately-invoked function expression” (IIFE) – nothing is executing itself. (It would be a perpetuum mobile if it were self-executing.) See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript

Comment: @RanjeetGautam it should - that sounds like a new question.